# How do I change the text overflow to ellipsis when there is no space

Tags: html, css

I have a container with some text and a button as seen below. 
The text on the top of the container is dynamic. It will be short sometimes or longer.

On larger screens it will have enough space to contain all the elements I want even if the text breaks into a second line as seen on the first row of the image below. (Not more than that).

On smaller screens, it can't even break into a second line because it won't have the height to contain everything.

[image]

What I want to do is, if there's enough space to break into a second line, the text should break into that second line.

But if the space is not enough, it should instead add an ellipsis.

Is there a way to do this with pure CSS?

Answer (score 3):

```css
.button {
  border:none;
  padding: 5px 10px;
  background-color: #000;
  color: #FFF;
  white-space: nowrap;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
  overflow: hidden;
  width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<button class="button">This text is way to long for this button</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

You need to disable breaking lines by setting `white-space` to `nowrap` and add `text-overflow` set to `ellipsis`:

```
.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

---

Sample:

```css
.container {
  width: 100px;
}

.ellipsis {
  white-space: nowrap;
  overflow: hidden;
  text-overflow: ellipsis;
}
```

```html
<div class="container ellipsis">
Very long long long text
</div>
```

Comment: Ah no. What I meant was, I want it to break into a second line if there's enough space to break. If the space is not enough it should add an ellipsis.

Comment: @user3607282 So you have two options: add media queries if you now when the box is to small or achieve it by javascript.

Answer (score 0):

If javascript is acceptable for you, there is [dotdotdot](http://dotdotdot.frebsite.nl/) plugin.